# Toggle method removes text highlight which ends up preventing execCommand from changing the highlighted text color

Tags: javascript

Hello so I notice my toggle method

removes the text highlight of the selected characters before the color picker is shown. Which prevents me from adding color to the characters that I had highlighted. This is what I mean

[image]

and plus this toggle method allows a user to click any where outside of the color picker, which also exits the color picker as well, so I want to maintain that still.

This is the kind of effect that I want but the way my code is. It cant do this.

[image]

So how can I get that kind of effect? Without losing the ability to toggle and clicking anywhere outside of the color picker to exit the color picker.

This is my code

```js
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

      /*<Add color>*/

    //Toggle the color picker

      var colorPicker = document.querySelector('#color-picker');
      colorPicker.addEventListener('click', function(execute) {
        execute.stopPropagation();
      });

      document.addEventListener('click', toggleTheColorPicker);

      function toggleTheColorPicker(event) {
        
        var colorPickerVar = document.querySelector('#color-picker');
        if (colorPickerVar.style.display === 'block') {
          colorPickerVar.style.display = 'none';
        } 
        
        else if (event.target.id == 'font-color') {
       document.querySelector('.document').focus();
          colorPickerVar.style.display = 'block';
        }
      }

    /**/

    //Pick a color

    var all_colors= document.querySelectorAll('#color-picker .colors');

    for(var i=0; i < all_colors.length; i++){
    all_colors[i].addEventListener('mousedown',function(event){event.preventDefault();});
    all_colors[i].addEventListener('click',fontColor);
    } 

    function fontColor(event){
      var color= event.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');
      document.execCommand('foreColor', false, color);
      
      document.querySelector('#color-picker').style.display= 'none';
      
    }

    /**/

    //Cancel the color picker 
    document.querySelector('#color-picker #cancel').addEventListener('click',cancelColorPicker);

    function cancelColorPicker(){
    document.querySelector('#color-picker').style.display= 'none';
    }
    /**/

    /*</Add color>*/

    });
```

```css
   /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Color picker
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    #font-color{
      background-color: gray;
      color: gold;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      cursor: pointer;
      
    }

    #color-picker{
      background-color: gray;
      height: 230px;
      width: 150px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: auto;
      display: none;
    }

    #color-picker #internal-container{
    /*   background-color: black; */
      overflow: auto;
      width: 120px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    #color-picker .color-container{
      position: relative;
    /*   background-color: blue; */
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
    /*   border: 1px solid black; */
      float: left;
    }

    #color-picker .colors{
      border-radius: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: auto;
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #color-picker #cancel{
    /*   background-color: red; */
      color: gold;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
         -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
           -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
            -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
                user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                      supported by Chrome and Opera */
    }  

    /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    document
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    .document{
        width:70vw;
        height: 50vh;
        margin: 2rem;
        padding: 1rem;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        box-shadow: 0 .1rem .4rem gray;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }


    .document:focus {
        outline: none !important;
       box-shadow: 0 .1rem .4rem silver;
        border: 1px solid white;
    }
```

```html
   <div id='font-color'>Font color</div>

    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Color picker
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

    <div id='color-picker'>
       
      <div id='internal-container'>
      
      <div class='color-container'>  
      <div id='white' class='colors' style='background-color: white;'></div>
      </div><!--</color-container>-->
      
      <div class='color-container'>   
      <div id='beige' class='colors' style='background-color: beige;'></div>
      </div><!--</color-container>-->
      
      <div class='color-container'>   
      <div id='yellow' class='colors' style='background-color: yellow;'></div>
      </div><!--</color-container>-->
      
      <div class='color-container'>
      <div id='gold' class='colors' style='background-color: gold;'></div>
      </div><!--</color-container>-->

      <div class='color-container'>
      <div id='orange' class='colors' style='background-color: orange;'></div>
     </div><!--</color-container>-->
        
      <div class='color-container'>
      <div id='pink' class='colors' style='background-color: pink;'></div>
      </div><!--</color-container>-->
      
      <div class='color-container'>
      <div id='violet' class='colors' style='background-color: violet;'></div>
      </div><!--</color-container>-->

      <div class='color-container'>  
      <div id='red' class='colors' style='background-color: red;'></div>
      </div><!--</color-container>-->
      
      <div class='color-container'>  
      <div id='dodgerblue' class='colors' style='background-color: dodgerblue;'></div>
      </div><!--</color-container>-->
        
      <div class='color-container'>  
      <div id='lime' class='colors' style='background-color: lime;'></div>  
      </div><!--</color-container>-->
        
      </div><!--<internal-container>-->
      
      <p id='cancel'>Cancel</p>
      
    </div><!--</color-picker>--> 


    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Document
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

    <div class='document' contenteditable='true'></div><!--</editor>-->
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you well, you just need to use an HTML `button` in your 'Font color' `div`

```
<button id='font-color'>Font color</button>
```

Here is your example (tested in Chromium): https://jsfiddle.net/3abnh4uj/1/

Hope this help or at least point you in the right direction :)